# Is my proof by induction correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

If $x_1 , x_2,......x_n$ are non-zero elements of a field so is $\prod_{k=1}^n x_k$; and
$\left(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{-1}$.

Assume $n = 2$ true;
How I did it:
First: 
$$P(1) \implies \prod_{k=1}^1 x_k = x_1 non zero$$ 
from condition so $P(1)$ holds true.

For $n = 2$ also holds true from assumption so $x_1 * x_2$ non zero.

For $m = n-1$, assume $$P(m) \implies x_1 * x_2 * .....x_m$$ is non zero holds true.

$$P(m+1) \implies \prod_{k=1}^{m+1} x_k = \prod_{k=1}^m x_k * x_{m+1}$$ 
We have $$\prod_{k=1}^m x_k non 0$$ from $P(m)$ and since $x_{m+1}$ non zero from condition, from monotonic axiom of multiplication $P(m+1)$ is true if $P(m)$ is. Induction complete.

Next:
$(\prod_{k=1}^n x_k)^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{-1}$

$P(1)$ holds true:
$$(\prod_{k=1}^1 x_k)^{-1} = (x_1)^{-1} = x_1^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^1 x_k^{-1}$$
Also for $n = 2$ we assume it to be true:
$$(\prod_{k=1}^2 x_k)^{-1 }= (x_1 * x_2)^{-1} = x_1^{-1} * x_2^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^2 x_k^{-1}$$
For $m = n-1$, assume $P(m)$ holds true.
$$P(m+1) = (\prod_{k=1}^{m+1} x_k)^{-1} = ((\prod_{k=1}^m x_k * x_{m+1})^{-1} = (\prod_{k=1}^m x_k)^{-1} * x_{m+1}^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^m x_k^{-1} * x_{m+1}^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{-1} \implies P(m+1)$$ 
holds true if $P(m)$ does.

Comment: I think this is very hard to read.

Comment: Note:  I tried to reformat it, but it was very hard going and I am sure I introduced some errors.  Please correct my version.  Much of the argument  doesn't make any sense to me.  For example:  what does $x>0$ mean in an arbitrary field?

Comment: Thank you, was formatting it myself. It means a non zero element

Comment: @CiaPan  That's happened to me several times...sorry to have done it to someone else!  I'm not editing it any more so feel free to patch it up.  I'm sure there are errors in what I did.

Comment: @lulu No problem, I'm new to this.

Comment: Just curious, what is the monotonic axiom of multiplication supposed to be? All you really have to do is prove it for $n=2$ and then apply associativity to conclude.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish It's my mistake somehow that axiom made sense to me at the moment. It's one of the axioms of ordered fields not sure what name it has but it states that if x, y, z from real number field and x> y then x+z> y+z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to read the given argument.  Roughly speaking, the idea looks ok but there is some confusion and it is unnecessarily complex.  In particular, $x>0$ has no meaning in the context of a general field and I have never heard of the "monotonic axiom of multiplication".

To answer the question:

As here, we'll proceed by induction.  For $n=1$ the claim is trivial. For $n=2$ we note that $a\neq 0$ implies that $a^{-1}$ exists so if we had $ab=0$ we could multiply by $a^{-1}$ to conclude that $b=0$.  Thus, if $b\neq 0$ we must have $ab\neq 0$ Now, For a general $n$ note that, inductively, $x_1x_2\dots x_{n-1}\neq 0$ so we can apply the same argument as for $n=2$ to conclude that $x_1\dots x_n\neq 0$.

To handle the inverse case, note that $x_i\neq 0\implies x_i^{-1}\neq 0$ so we can simply apply the first case to $\{x_1^{-1},\dots,x_n^{-1}\}$

Comment: Yes you are right, I actually meant non zero element there, edited it.